# Blender compositor's RGB Curves don't match Photoshop's (or behaves correctly)

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, color-management

I'm trying to port some Photoshop curve presets of mine into Blender, in hopes of creating a library of "looks" I can apply to the compositor via the Asset Library. However, it's not going as well as I'd hoped, as Blender's RGB curves behave quite strangely to other curve editors in other programs.

Here's an example.
[image: Comparison of curve handling]

- The first image, is the source image, no effects or color correction.
  It's simply a render saved from Blender (AgX, sRGB, if that matters).
- The second image, is the source image, processed using curves in PS. Specifically, the curves in the "Camera Raw" fiter, however using the curves adjustment layer reaches a similar effect and is still drastically different to Blender's result.
- The third image, is a render inside Blender, and composited, using
  the same curve values from PS. The same as if you had just pressed
  F12, rendered the scene, and let the compositor it do its thing.
- The final image, is the source image, imported into the compositor
  with an image node, followed by an RGB curves node (values obviously
  same as before).

Now it doesn't take an expert to see that there's a large difference between how Blender processes the curves compared to PS.
For posterity, here's the curves side by side (PS on left, Blender on right, CRGB overlayed).
[image: Curves]
They're the same curve. Or at least close enough to make the discrepancy negligible.
*To make sure they're the same curve*, I copied the values from PS to Blender. As PS uses a 0-255 scale, I divided these values by 255 to fit into Blender's 0-1 format for the curves.

From my testing, the view transform when rendering doesn't seem to fix the issue, and changing the color space when compositing an imported image largely doesn't do much, with one exception. Using RAW makes things less "horrible" (probably because it significantly drops the values of the image), however the result still is drastically different to PS.

I'm not sure what the issue is, and I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out. I knew going in that a 1:1 conversion of the presets was going to be impossible, but at most I figured the colors would be slightly different, not a completely borked image like what I'm getting though.

I'm attatching a .blend file of the scene in the examples. It uses the same RGB curve as the examples.

https://files.catbox.moe/y6mz4j.blend

If anyone knows what's going on, I'd sure appreciate the help. Ideally, I'd like it to work straight from the compositor without exporting to an image. So F12 to render the scene, compositor

Comment: I'm not so much the expert for the technical things, but you cannot simply convert the 0-255 range from PS into the 0-1 range of Blender. Because after rendering with F12, the render result you are working on in the _Compositor_ still has the full dynamic range. Values can be way higher beyond 1 (only the display limits them to 1), and the colors are linear and only the color management gives them a certain look. And when you save the result as a JPG or PNG those color transforms are baked in and more important: they are no longer linear and reduced to the 0-255 range.

Comment: The range for those values are simply how PS or Blender interprets it. The numbers associated with the limits of either range in this case are pretty arbitrary. It's the same thing as normal RGB color values in the color picker being converted in Blender to 0-1 values. 255,0,0 is the exact same red as 1.0, 0, 0 (even down to the hex code). The only difference is the number scheme used.

It's got nothing to do with dynamic range, color spaces, or color management. Swapping the color management profile doesn't suddenly change the range of the color picker to something different.

Comment: Besides, I'm not converting color spaces from 0-255 to 0-1. I'm simply putting the curve points in the same place using simple math. Dynamic range or not, if the points are in the same place, the result *should* be similar.

Comment: But the render result which you are working on in the compositor can have values above the 0-1 range, first of all - even if the display only shows RGB values from 0 to 255. Therefore working on curves gives different results because the render is not limited to the range of the curve. For example, in the _Compositor_ you can darken the image with an _Exposure_ node set to -3, and the moon in the HDRI sky is still quite bright. If you use an adjustment layer in PS to lower the exposure by -3 on a JPG, the moon becomes dark grey.